# Detecting changepoint in ratio of rates of two Poisson processes

Tags: change-point, poisson-process

I'm interested in a changepoint detection problem of the following scenario:

Consider two Poisson processes for which we have the event times.  I'm interested in detecting a change in the *relative* intensities of the processes, normalizing out fluctuations in the combined/joint intensity.

Furthermore, one class is much rarer than the other, and as usual, it's the rare one which is the interesting business case (this is for a real application, not academic).

For example in a web commerce application, the processes might represent clicks or page hits, and the interesting ones might be ones which converted to a sale, and could be but 1% or 0.1% or 0.01% of the total.  You can imagine many other problems with a similar structure, such as detecting anomalies in internet communications (cyber security), industrial control (failure events) or financial transactions (risk).

I'm interested in detecting a significant change (step or better yet ramp up) in 'hit rate' (if you count that as which fraction of clicks were converted to sales vs total rate /misses) but reasonably independent of both short term common dynamics or long-term trends of the overall volume. That is, a relative rate increase of both the rare and common process to the same degree is not interesting. I'd also like to avoid significant modeling or assumptions on the overall rate as that could vary for all sorts of unknown and uncontrollable reasons.

I'd rather not impose arbitrary time boundaries for quantization/summation if not necessary but I'm open to any practical approaches.

Early detection of a real change is very valuable in the business context.

Computational efficiency should also be important as the data volume could be very large, as there would be potentially millions of these streams (each with a two-class pair of processes) and being alerted which one may be changing structure (and an estimate of when) is quite valuable.

Does anybody know of any approaches, literature or software for this problem?

It seems as though it should have been addressed somewhere already given the general nature of the problem.

Comment: In epidemiology when monitoring disease outbreaks space-time scan statistics are popular - see the [SatScan software](http://www.satscan.org/) and its library for examples. Basically what it does is calculates the rate for various window sizes and then identifies anomalous windows based on simulated test statistics.